# Select2 - Link on formatNoMatches

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) to enhance my `<select>` input. I populate the `<options>` with coldfusion and sql.  I want to use `formatNoMatches` to add the option if there are no matches in the user search.  I don't want to use a multiple select because it does not work with my coldfusion, plus it would be much simpler to simply add a click event to `formatNoMatches`.

Somewhere in select2.js, there is code that is stopping mouse events from occurring for `formatNoMatches`.  Is there a way to hack it that will allow mouse events?

```js
$(".select").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    blurOnChange: true,
    openOnEnter: false,
    formatNoMatches: function(term) {
        return "<a href='#' onclick='alert('" + term + "');'"
          + "id='newClient'>Add New Client</a>";
    }
});
```

I can't get the above code to alert anything.

Comment: Is select2.js a file that you wrote yourself?

Comment: no it is a jquery plug in

Comment: FYI, updated question to include plugin link ie http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: There are many `stopPropagation()` in the plugin and certainely one of them prevents to use a link on `NoMatches`. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with select2. There is a bug for the same. But till now no solution. Some idea is there, you can find the details below.

https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/276

Answer (score 0):

Use the select2 createSearchChoice function to allow the user to input their own option.  Then use the change event on select2 to listen for any new search choices and launch a mini-form or unhide a link on the page to add additional details if a custom choice is selected.