# Select2 custom meessage doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to make a link to create new object when no results were found. I'm using Rails 4. I've included gem `gem "select2-rails"`, added `//= require select2` in application.js and

```
*= require select2
*= require select2-bootstrap
```

in application.js. Here's my coffeescript which should work fine (ajax working well) but function `formatNoMatches` seems to do nothing.

```
$('#invoice_client_id').select2
    theme: 'bootstrap'
    formatNoMatches: (term) ->
      return "<a href='#' onclick='alert('" + term + "');'" + "id='newClient'>Add New Client</a>";
    ajax:
      url: '/clients.json'
      dataType: 'json'
      processResults: (data) ->
        return {
        results: $.map(data, (client, i) ->
          {
            id: client.id
            text: client.name
          }
       )}
```

I have found in documentation no mentions of `formatNoMatches` but in a lot of user examples it's used to do same thing [like here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070401/select2-link-on-formatnomatches)

### EDIT

Link or custom text doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Does the link appear but not work or does it not appear at all? And which version of Select2 are you using?

Comment: @JawadKhawaja does not appear at all. I'm using Select2 4.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around a bit and found this way of doing it in the 4.0+ versions.

```
$('select').select2
    language:
        noResults: ->
             return "<a href='http://google.com'>Add</a>";

    escapeMarkup: (markup) ->
        return markup;
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Can you tell me where'd you find this solution?

Maybe you also know how to call a function after returning this link? I have a function which edit behaviour of some links to open them in window, but I need to call this function after html objects are created.

Comment: Regarding using a function, maybe you could check if the plugin provides callbacks. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: If you don't find any callbacks, you could try `setTimeOut(your_function_call(), 5000)` right above the `return` line in `noResults` function to simulate a delay of 5 seconds. If that works, your function would execute after the link has been added to the DOM.